# What is the purpose having final keyword in method parameter?

Tags: java, final

I recently saw a method like

```
public void display(final String toDisplay){

}
```

I want to know the purpose of `final` keyword in method parameter.

Comment: Wht exactly u didn't understand? bcoz if its again explained, it might not be wht u want.

Comment: I mean you can't get any clearer than that.

Comment: so you can have a Fantasy class and declare it as final Fantasy

Comment: @Lokesh The language that the answers I went had was very tough to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final` variables means you can not change the value.

For example `final int x=9;` and after that if you change it with `x=6;` then it will not compile.

So in your case

```
public void display(final String toDisplay){

}
```

In this method you are allowing a `String` argument and after that within that method if you try to change then it will not compile.

Comment: Thanks that was simple enough.

Comment: what is the point of this? any "changes" would be to the locally scoped reference, and not to the actual object, so clients cannot possibly see any difference, right?

Answer (score 2):

suppose your method doing complex calculation so by accidentally you may not change the value of **toDisplay**  variable this is the main reason I can say.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get your answer

Answer (score 1):

It is to make sure that the implementation will not change the reference.

Answer (score 0):

It simply tells the compiler that this method can not change the thing that parameter points to.